# Sql Try Catch with while-loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, try-catch

I have been struggling to get this little bit of code to corrected.  I am hoping someone can help. I must be missing something.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.  During an archive process we go through a process of deleting thousands to millions of rows from many tables.  Some deletes processes take longer than others.  So what I am trying to do is Catch any errors during a run and notify me via email.  As well I am want to email me when the delete completes.

The INTERVAL code works great with the delete and is necessary for our process.  I am only trying to correctly add a Try..Catch Block to send emails.

Here is how this performs today when testing.
When I run the Select 1/0 instead of the Delete to force an error.  I will get the "FAILED" email.  However I will also get the "COMPLETED" email.  In this case I would only be looking for the Failed email.  Also for the email and the "print" line the @Totalcount variable is not getting filled from this line - SET @TOTALCOUNT = @TOTALCOUNT + @CHECKCOUNT

When I run the code below as a DELETE with no failures I get the "COMPLETED" email.  Although there is still the issue with the @totalcount variable getting filled for the email and the print line.

I have moved the completed SET Variables and Completed email code to the TRY block and haven't had much luck. I have tried so many variations of Nesting Try blocks and moving the BREAK but i just can't see to get it right.  Any help and guidance would be great appreciated.
Thanks

```
 DECLARE
 @INTERVAL INT
,@CHECKCOUNT INT
,@TOTALCOUNT INT
,@starttime DATETIME
,@endDELtime DATETIME
,@endtime DATETIME

 SET @starttime = GETDATE()

 SET @INTERVAL = 10

 SET @TOTALCOUNT = 0

 WHILE 1 = 1 

 BEGIN  
   BEGIN TRY    

    --SELECT 1/0;
    DELETE TOP (@INTERVAL)
        FROM dbo.specphone
         WHERE SPEC IN 
                    (
                     SELECT
                          SPEC
                    FROM dbo.tblGeneral (NOLOCK)
                    )

  END TRY   

BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @err_msg AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @endDELtime = GETDATE()
    SET @err_msg = 'Severity - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ERROR_SEVERITY()) + 
    CHAR(13) +
     'Error Number - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ERROR_NUMBER()) + CHAR(13) +
     'Error Message - ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() + CHAR(13) +
     'tblspecphone:  ' + 'Total Count ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TOTALCOUNT) + 
      CHAR(13) + 
            ' Start Time is ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @starttime) + CHAR(13) +
            ' End Time is ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @endDELtime) ;

        --SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber;
        --SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
            @profile_name = 'default',  
            @recipients = 'gdh@isp.com',  
            @subject = 'FAILED - Archive Project Delete Script',
            @body = @err_msg;
END CATCH                   


    SET @CHECKCOUNT = @@RowCount 

    SET @TOTALCOUNT = @TOTALCOUNT + @CHECKCOUNT

    IF @CHECKCOUNT = 0

    SET @endtime = GETDATE()

    DECLARE
    @bodymsg AS VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @bodymsg = 'The Delete Query has finished.  Verify and Proceed on 
    with next script if no Errors.' + CHAR(13) + 
        'tblspecphone:  ' + 'Total Count ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TOTALCOUNT) + 
         CHAR(13) + 
            ' Start Time is ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @starttime) + CHAR(13) 
              +
            ' End Time is ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @endtime)

        BEGIN   
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
        @profile_name = 'default',  
        @recipients = 'gdh@isp.com',  
        @body = @bodymsg,   
        @subject = 'Completed - Archive Project Delete Script'; 
        END

       BREAK

     END    


    PRINT '

         tblspecphone:  ' + 'Total Count ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TOTALCOUNT) + 
      ' Start Time is ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @starttime) + ' End Time is ' 
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @endtime)
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Answer (score 1):

Put a boolean variable, set it to false inside catch, and then use it to determine wether to send the COMPLETE email.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your mistake is the "break"; it sould be in the while-loop and not in the catch-block and should be checked against a variable like omoret mentioned

Example:

```
DECLARE @error int
SET @error = 0
DECLARE @i int
SET @i = 5
WHILE @i > -2
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
       SELECT 1 / @i
       PRINT 'it is ok to divide by ' + cast(@i as varchar)
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
       PRINT 'ERROR'
       SET @error = 1 
    END CATCH
    IF @error = 1 
       BREAK;

    SET @i = @i - 1
END
```